# R: nested loop with non-numeric index

Tags: r, vectorization

I am a political science student and learning R. I have a problem with a nested loop, one of my indices being non-numeric.
I have a data frame `pwt` containing, for each country in the world (column `country`) and each year from 1950 to 2011 (column `year`) a number of development indicators, among which is GDP. 
I would like to add a column that contains the % change in GDP from a year to the next.

Here is the error I get:

```
Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = numeric(0)):  replacement has length zero

GDPgrowth = rep("NA", length(pwt$country))
pwt <- cbind.data.frame(pwt, GDPgrowth)
countries <- unique(pwt$country)
for(i in countries)  # for each country
{
  for(j in 1951:2011) # for each year
  {
    pwt[pwt$country == i & pwt$year == j,"GDPgrowth"] = (pwt[pwt$country == i 
& pwt$year == j,"rdgpo"]/pwt[pwt$country == i & pwt$year == j-1,"rdgpo"] - 
1)*100
  }
}
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Convert the factor column to character i.e. `pwt$country <- as.character(pwt$country)` (based on the error)

Comment: No unfortunately I keep getting the same error

Comment: In that case, please provide a small reproducible example and expected output based on that input data.

Comment: It would be `as.numeric(pwt$GDPgrowth)` as that is the field in which you are replaceing values

Comment: Nested loops can usually be eliminated in R. In this case, the `for(i in countries)` with a group-by on `country` column, and the `for(j in 1951:2011)` by vectorizing the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

For this sort of rolling/thing-over-thing, etc. you can use [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html), [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html), or [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). I personally prefer the latter for its flexibility and (running) speed for large datasets. Vs. using a loop, these will generally be faster and more syntactically convenient.

Assuming your data looks something like this (numbers obviously made up):

```
country year rgdp
USA     1991 1000
USA     1992 1200
USA     1993 1500
SWE     1991 1000
SWE     1992 900
SWE     1993 2000
```

You can use data.table's shift to calculate values from leading/lagging values. In this case:

```
library(data.table)

pwt <- as.data.table(list(country=c("USA", "USA", "USA", "SWE", "SWE", "SWE"),
                          year=c(1991, 1992, 1993, 1991, 1992, 1993),
                          rgdp=c(1000, 1200, 1500, 1000, 900, 2000)))

pwt[, growth := rgdp/shift(rgdp, n=1, type="lag") - 1, by=c("country")]
```

Gives:

```
country year rgdp growth
USA     1991 1000 NA
USA     1992 1200 0.200000
USA     1993 1500 0.250000
SWE     1991 1000 NA
SWE     1992 900 -0.100000
SWE     1993 2000 1.222222
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use `diff` from base `R`. This is used to calculate difference between immediate values

```
difference<-c(0,diff(pwd$gdp))
```

This would give you difference between consecutive GDP's which you can easily use to find percentage grouth.

PS: SO is to help people out and not provide exact solution and spoon feed. Thus this answer just points you in a direction and not gives you exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid the loop:

```
p <- pwd[, c('country', 'year', 'rdgpo')]
p$year <- p$year + 1
colnames(p)[3] <- 'rdgpo_prev'

pwd <- merge(pwd, p, all.x=TRUE)
pwd$GDPgrowth <- 100 * ((pwd$rdgpo/pwd$rdgpo_prev) -1)
pwd$rdgpo_prev <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

By the same token another convenient solution avoiding the loop can be achieved with use of `dplyr`.

```
# Install and data download -----------------------------------------------

# World Bank Data pkg
install.packages('WDI')
require(WDI)

#' Source data
#' NYGDPMKTPCD correspond to "GDP, PPP (constant 2005 international $)"
#' Check WDIsearch() for codes
pwt <- WDI(country = "all", indicator = "NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD",
           start = 1951, end = 2011, extra = FALSE, cache = NULL)

# Percentage change on panel data -----------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
pwt <- pwt %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(pct.chg = 100 * 
               ((NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD - lag(NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD))/lag(NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD)))
```

---

As a side point I would suggest that, in line with the SO guidelines, you provide reproducible example. In terms of major publicly available statistical repositories (Eurostat, OECD, World Bank, etc.) there are R packagaes and tutorials that make sourcing the desired data effortless. In the example above I'm using the [WDI](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/WDI) package to source the World Bank data.

## Edit

Finally, if you insist on making things in the loop you can do it like that:

```
for (i in unique(pwt$country))  {
    # Assuming that years are incomplete
    for (j in unique(pwt$year[pwt$country == i])) {
        # As the DF is simple i simply used column numbers
        pwt[which(
            pwt$year == j & 
                pwt$country == i) +1 ,6] <- 100 * ((pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                  pwt$country == i)  +1 ,3]
                                                    - pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                    pwt$country == i),3]) 
                                                   / abs(pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                       pwt$country == i),3]))
    }
}
```

The solution could be less explicit but I wanted to emphasise the need of picking the right row for each combination of **year** and **country** that is implemented in the `which` statement.

### Benchmarking

The loop approach appears to be rather inefficient:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dpl_sol(), bse_sol(), times = 1)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
 dpl_sol()    21.26792    21.26792    21.26792    21.26792    21.26792    21.26792     1
 bse_sol() 94573.05671 94573.05671 94573.05671 94573.05671 94573.05671 94573.05671     1
```

#### Benchmarked functions from above

```
dpl_sol <- function() {
    pwt <- pwt %>%
        group_by(country) %>%
        arrange(year) %>%
        mutate(pct.chg = 100 * 
                   ((NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD - lag(NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD))/lag(NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD)))
}
bse_sol <- function() {
    pwt$pct.chg2 <- NA # Column 6
    for (i in unique(pwt$country))  {
        # Assuming that years are incomplete
        for (j in unique(pwt$year[pwt$country == i])) {
            # As the DF is simple i simply used column numbers
            pwt[which(
                pwt$year == j & 
                    pwt$country == i) +1 ,6] <- 100 * ((pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                      pwt$country == i)  +1 ,3]
                                                        - pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                        pwt$country == i),3]) 
                                                       / abs(pwt[which(pwt$year == j & 
                                                                           pwt$country == i),3]))
        }
    }

}
```